# How To Prevent Plot Title From Overlapping With Chart in Pandas Boxplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

If I run the following code:

```
df.boxplot(column='Age', by='Embarked', grid=False)
```

I get the following chart:

[image]

How does one change the padding on either the chart of the title so they don't overlap?

Comment: When I run this, I [get no overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55z9X.png).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I do get overlap on matplotlib 3.0.1 and pandas 0.24.2.

Comment: matpltib 3.1 will now do this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with the usual

```
df.boxplot(column='Age', by='Embarked', grid=False)
plt.show()
```

However, I was able to separate the headers by passing an axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
df.boxplot(column='Age', by='Embarked', ax=ax, grid=False)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]